# Elsevier format 2 columns in Lyx

Tags: lyx, two-column, elsarticle

I would like to use Elsevier class to create paper in 2 column format as shown in authors guide: http://cdn.elsevier.com/assets/pdf_file/0011/109388/elsdoc.pdf (last page). I am using Lyx and kept the settings as follows: Document Settings->Document Class-> article(Elsevier). 
I understand that there are various formats and it is easy for LaTex users as everything is explained in detail. 
It would be really helpful if someone could please guide on 'how can I get the above mentioned format in Lyx'.
I have tried Text Layout->'Two-column Document' but everything gets jumbled up.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Sorry wrong post!

Comment: It is possible that `elsarticle` is not compatible with LyX (I don't know). Instead of using the LyX options, you can try to modify directly the preamble and add `[twocolumn]` or `[5p]` as a parameter to the class, the first line of the header should become `\documentclass[twocolumn]{elsarticle}` or `\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}`. If this is not possible, try adding `\PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{elsarticle}` before `\documentclass`.

Comment: elsarticle is compatible as it is provided with the Lyx as well. I have few doubts: There is a option LaTeX preamble but when I add there it gives error. Where should I add [twocolumn] or [5p] is there a way to add it like \usepackage ,etc.? In Lyx, there is no command begin document or end, so where should I add what you said before/after title/abstract/introduction?

Comment: I don't know how to vote your comment but I have figured the solution, you answer was the clue :) Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I figured the solution to add 2 columns from the hint by tohecz. People who want to create 2 columns need to just add: Document Class->(in) Custom (type-->) 5p (5p without brackets, quotes,etc.).

Answer (score 0):

To add to dbs's answer, see `\documentclass` [usage at Elsevier.com](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiIhpb4j9zLAhWBVyYKHZPAAtQQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elsevier.com%2F__data%2Fassets%2Fpdf_file%2F0008%2F56843%2Felsdoc-1.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFPh7scDi6DkjnXOiiy04ISEoOrGw&sig2=sX-0w7Q6EdjxFz31UxLS8g). The class should be loaded with the command: `\documentclass[<options>]{elsarticle}` where the options can be the following:

`preprint` default option which format the document for submission to Elsevier journals. Along with this option `\date{Custom date}` can be provided which will be printed in preprint line in footer.

`nopreprintline` Suppresses the preprint line in the footer of the first page including the date.

`review` similar to the `preprint` option, but increases the baselineskip to facilitate an easier review process.

`1p` formats the article to the look and feel of the final format of model 1+ journals. This is always of single column style.

`3p` formats the article to the look and feel of the final format of model 3+ journals. If the journal is a two column model, use `twocolumn` option in combination.

`5p` formats for model 5+ journals. This is always of two column style.

`authoryear` author–year citation style of `natbib.sty`.